# express route unable to get

Tags: node.js, express

I have a route file for the admin and home pages separately. I also have difference layout files for home and admin. When I access the home and admin routes on my local dev everything is ok, but when I try to access the admin route useing site.com/admin I get Cannot GET /admin/ response. following is my server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');


const app = express();


// Use path
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Map Global Promise
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// Connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/skillbuild')
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

// Load Idea model
// require('./models/Idea');
// const Idea = mongoose.model('ideas');

// Express Handlebars middleware
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'main'
}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// BodyParser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Method Override middleware
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

// Load routes
const home = require('./routes/home');
const admin = require('./routes/admin');


// Use routes
app.use('/', home);
app.use('/admin', admin);

// Express session middleware
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(flash());

// Global variables
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
    res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    next();
});




const port = 80;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

my home routes which are in home.js routes file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.all('/*', (req, res, next) => {
    req.app.locals.layout = 'main';
    next();
});

// index route 
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});


// About route 
router.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.render('about');
});


//login route temp 
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('users/login');
});

module.exports = router;
```

my admin.js routes file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.all('/*', (req, res, next) => {
    req.app.locals.layout = 'admin';
    next();
});

// admin index route 
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('admin/index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I think you should provide port also like site.com:80/admin

Comment: No that does not work as well. besides the port has been set to 80 already which is the default port for http so there is not need to define it explicitly I think.

Answer (score 0):

OK...so the problem simply was that I needed to restart the server with pm2 restart id of the node app in order to load the updated code. Problem solved.